# New to react and getting data from axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I know my data exists and I can see it within the async function but when I pass it out its just the promise.

Two part question; how do I pass this data outside of the async function and how do I use within my react component? I considered just using handlebars but I have been wanting to figure out react.

Just trying loop through the data. I know how to do with jquery and xhttp requests. Fighting the async / promise function.

```
const Books = () => {
    const [bookData, setBookData] = React.useState('');
    async function getDat () {
   const res = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coderxdesigner/bookstore/main/src/json/childrens.json');
   const data = await res.json();
     return data;
}
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <h1>Books</h1>
            {console.log(data.book.map(itm => itm.title))}          
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

Comment: You never use `getDat` not `setBookData`

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] the question's title to fall in line with the recommendations in that article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `React.useEffect(() => { /* Execute what ever you want */ }, [])` and `setBookData`.

The useEffect is in order to execute something when the components loads (Thats why `[]` is present there, that means that when the component loads it activates)

The setBookData is in order to update the value of `bookData`, so when you execute `setBookData(data)` then the value `bookData` will update automatically in your react render. Here is the code:

```js
const Books = () => {
  const [bookData, setBookData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coderxdesigner/bookstore/main/src/json/childrens.json');
      const data = await res.json();
      setBookData(data.book);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <h1>Books</h1>
      {bookData.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to the docs to check out the useEffect. This fixed my issue.